python drop on specific column in an excel file
Hi I drop some empty value on a specific column
# Drop rows from column_name df.dropna(subset=['column_name'], inplace=True) df
But there was a string left with this value ""
I would like to drop that also. Thank you for your help.

df = df[df['column_name'].notna() & (df['column_name'] != '')] or df.drop(df[df['column_name'].isin(['', None])].index, inplace=True)
